# Infopath form publishing to SharePoint 2016 issues

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I am facing issues in publishing Infopath form to SharePoint 2016. I ensured all the prerequisites(features, service applications, infopath services configuration, perimssion for the user account that is publishing) are satisfied.
http://www.appvity.com/blogs/post/2013/06/16/How-to-configure-and-publish-InfoPath-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx

I am trying to publish an Infopath form to the SharePoint server 2016. It is a simple from with a single text control. I kept the form simple to test the publishing process.

The Publishing process is going fine upto the following screen
[image]

After this screen, i am getting the error.

[image]

There is no error message by Microsoft.

I checked ULS Logs. There is no error messages there.

Can any one help me how to follow from here?

---

**Update on 3/20/2019:**

Investigation with fiddler revealed problem with the Update Content Type. The response is

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"> <soap:Body> <UpdateContentTypeResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/"> <UpdateContentTypeResult> <Results> <Method ID="2"> <ErrorCode>0x00000000</ErrorCode> </Method>
```

Comment: Additional information: I debug using fiddler, the library is created and deleted.

Comment: do you get the error as well when you try to edit an list form (create a test list and modify the default form with infopath)?

Comment: @MarekSarad, I will do what you said and update.

Comment: @MarekSarad, the editing of list forms is working perfectly fine. The problem is with the form library.

Comment: with your first comment what do you mean the library is created and deleted? I should have the form library created before you publish the form to it.

Comment: @MarekSarad, when the infopath publishing is failed, then I go to recycle bin of my site collection. I find the newly created list as part of publishing in the recycle bin

Comment: Try first to create a form library and then publish the form.

Comment: @MarekSarad, Thank you. I found the root cause and resolved the issues.

Answer (score 2):

One of the prerequisite for publishing infopath is "enabling Desktop experience feature". As my dev server is a "Single farm server", I enabled "Desktop experience feature" and the publishing issues are resolved.

See the following Microsoft KB: support.office.com/en-us/article/-infopath-cannot-save-the-following-form-error-message-when-you-try-to-publish-an-infopath-form-on-a-sharepoint-server-2013-server-7419903b-1bae-4f93-bec8-d01526f04806

Thanks to @MarekSarad